# Port Routing between different domains

Tags: proxy, nat, subdomain, port

i have a apache server located on **a.com:9254** 
I would like to route a.y.com:80 to a.com:9254. So, I can put all my services under y.com domain.

I tried proxy. However, In apache, it looks all requests comes from same ip. It fails my security system. I can not change it. I need a full transparent solution.

Maybe NAT can be a solution, but I don't have enough knowledge..

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The apache reverse proxy is the best solution for what you need. You just need to change the apache log format of the a.com:9254 site to include the X-Forwarded-For.

See the example took from http://www.techstacks.com/howto/log-client-ip-and-xforwardedfor-ip-in-apache.html

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" proxy
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^.*\..*\..*\..*" forwarded
CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined env=!forwarded
CustomLog "logs/access_log" proxy env=forwarded
```

Another solution is to use a iframe on a.y.com and embed the a.com:9254 site in the iframe element.

Answer (score 0):

routing is used for layer 3... (IPs) only.  You're talking about forwarding a port... which is  done by "NATing"

NATing changes IPs... and is probably not what you're looking for.  You should simply setup a "redirect" on server "a.y.com" to "a.com:9254".  mod_rewrite can help you with this.

Comment: I think that he wants to hide that the pages are served by a.com:9254 and display a.y.com in the browser.

Comment: He did indicate that he was going to **move** the site from a.y.com to a.com:port  ... but I did +1 your answer too.  Very good solution too.